# positioning list items

Tags: html, css

Ok, I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/25J3M/6/ , I want to position the red and yellow blocks just like the black and blue ones, red below the black one and the yellow below the blue one

```
<ul class="tracks">
    <li class="bateria"></li>
    <li class="waveform-bateria"></li>
    <li class="guitarra"></li>
    <li class="waveform-guitarra"></li>
</ul>​
```

```
/* track */

ul .tracks {
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    left:0px;
    list-style-type:none;    
}

ul.tracks li.bateria {
    width:348px;
    height:279px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-right:0;
    float:left;
}

ul.tracks .waveform-bateria {
    width:678px;
    height:278px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-right:0;
    float:left;    
    clear:right;
}

ul.tracks li.guitarra {
    width:348px;
    height:279px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-right:0;
    float:left;
}


ul.tracks .waveform-guitarra {
    width:678px;
    height:278px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-right:0;
    float:left;    
}
```

Comment: So that the red one overlaps the blue one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make them all the same height (the `.waveform-*` ones are one pixel shorter on the height). Also, remove the `margin-top` from `.guitarra` (which is only on your jsfiddle, not on the code you posted).

Finally, keep in mind this layout will only work if the user's browser window has at least 1026px available on the width, otherwise `.waveform-*` will break to the next line.

http://jsfiddle.net/25J3M/14/